# Пропадает окошко Terminal в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, консоль, windows-10

При нажатии на вкладку Terminal в Android Studio, окошко консоли появляется на долю секунды и исчезает. Приходится пользоваться стандартной командной строкой от Windows, что вызывает некоторые неудобства. Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему? 
Возникла данная проблема после обновления Android Studio. Сейчас установлена последняя версия AS и Windows10 (Я слышал, что проблемы с терминалом в AS часто возникают именно в этой версии Windows).

Comment: переустанавливать пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал, проблема остаётся

Comment: а плагин терминала у вас стоит?

Comment: можно еще так попробовать - `Tools-> Android-> Enable ADB Integration`

Comment: Плагин терминала стоит, а в меню Tools не нашёл пункта Android

Comment: попробуйте переустановить плагин или сделать выкл - вкл, возможно у него затык какой-то произошел

Comment: Спасибо за советы, но тоже не сработало...

Comment: Посмотрите лог студии - может там какая зацепка обнаружится: `Menu->Help->Show Log in Explorer->idea.log` (последние записи в конце файла).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привёл наконец-то терминал в работоспособное состояние, хотя до конца так и не понял, в чём была проблема.

В Android Studio зашёл в File-Settings-Tools-Terminal. В разделе Application settings в графе Shell Path был указан путь C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe. Вместо git.exe указал путь к файлу bash.exe (C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe) и всё заработало.